# Blank spaces when using geom_scatterpie

Tags: r, pie-chart, scatterpie

Good afternoon,

I am using geom_scatterpie (R) to plot pies in different locations around the world. For some of the pies, I have blank spaces and I don't know how to fix the issue

[image]

I checked the sum of the percentage for each site and it is equal to 1.

Did anyone had the same issue and have found a solution to fix it?

Thank you very much for your help,
Cheers,
Salma.

```
# World map
world <- map_data('world')
world
p2 <- ggplot(world, aes(long, lat)) +
    geom_map(map=world, aes(map_id=region), fill=NA, color="black") +
    coord_quickmap()

#Increase the size of the axis text and axis titles of the world map
p2 <-  p2 + labs(x = "Longitude") + labs(y = "Latitude") +
                      theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18, color = "black")) + 
                      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 18, color = "black")) + 
                      theme(axis.title = element_text( face="bold", size=28)) + 
                      labs(fill="") #add a title to the legend


p2 <-  p2 + geom_scatterpie(aes(x=POINT_X, y=POINT_Y, group=region, r=radius*350, sorted_by_radius = TRUE), data=classification, cols=c("No data", "Stable", "Accretion", "Erosion", "Extreme erosion", "Intense erosion", "Severe erosion"),  alpha=0.7) + coord_equal()+ geom_scatterpie_legend(classification$radius, x=-200, y=-50, n=3)

# legend title
p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=18, 
                                      face="bold"))
# legend labels
p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=18))

colors <- c( '#4575b4','#fee090', '#fdae61', '#f46d43','#DCDCDC', '#d73027', '#e0f3f8' )  

p2 <- p2 +  scale_fill_manual(name = "",  values = colors)
```

Comment: Please, could you share your `classification` dataset ? You can paste the output of `dput(classification)`.